# I can't run tests

Tags: django

I'm trying to run my tests, on my virtual environment, so when I run the command:

```
python server/manage.py test --settings=skillcorner.settings_test api
```

I get the following Error:

```
> File "server/manage.py", line 8
>      print(f'Running with settings: {os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]}')
>                                            ^
>      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so I run (on my virtual environment) the command (I just used python3 instead of python:
    `python3 server/manage.py test --settings=skillcorner.settings_test api`

I get the following error, which is the one I am stuck on:

```
> Running with settings: skillcorner.settings_local
>      Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "server/manage.py", line 12, in <module>
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>      File "/home/yosra/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>     utility.execute()
>     File "/home/yosra/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 357, in execute
>     django.setup() File "/home/yosra/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py",
> line 24, in setup
>     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>     File "/home/yosra/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
> line 91, in populate
>     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
>     File "/home/yosra/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
> line 90, in create
>     module = import_module(entry)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
>     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
>     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework
```

I can't figure out how to fix this, I tried to install rest-framework using ppip install,  but it doesn't work!

Comment: and `python manage.py runserver --settings=skillcorner.settings_local` works?

Comment: `/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py` it doesn't look like virtualenv path - are you sure you activated it?

Comment: yes I am sure that's the first thing I did, I activated my virtual environment using: $source venv/bin/activate

Comment: yes python manage.py runserver works, the migration works too

Comment: Can you also please confirm whether you have added 'rest_framework' to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings?
Thanks

Comment: yes I added them, but I just found the origin of the error! to run my tests I had to create a database, and to do so, I used sudo to have all the permissions, which I shouldn't have done, because once I use sudo, I won't we working with my virtual environment's python installation but the one of the sudo user instead

Comment: Install Django's REST framework first. You have it in your INSTALLED_APPS but you don't have it in your virtual environment. `pip install djangorestframework`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really tell how you manage your virtual environment but I am pretty sure the issue is there. I would assume the following:

- The first error you get is indeed because of the `f'{something}'` formatting that was introduced with python 3.6 (and thus causes an error in python2)
- The second error you get is because you are missing `rest_framework` in the environment you are running Python3.

My suggestion:

- Delete your whole environment folder and make sure you `deactivate` it
- Run `python3 -m venv venv` in the terminal to create a new environment
- Activate it: `source venv/bin/activate`
- Install your dependencies from `requirements.txt` or `pip install django djangorestframework` (and any other dependencies of your project)
- You can then just do `python manage.py whatevercommand` or `./manage.py whatevercommand` for short (both will run python3 if you have the environment activated)

A last hint: you can check you current python version (in the env or jsut anywhere) with `python --version`